# GREP find minimal and maximal number

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a file *query.txt*, each line of the file represents a number, 
using **grep** command i have to find all lines that have a number *10 < x < 100*

How should i write it ?

Comment: 10 and 100 should or should not match? Is it for integers or real numbers in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grep is the wrong tool to use.

try this one-liner:

```
awk '($0+0)>10 && ($0+0)<100' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

`grep "^..$" query.txt | grep -v 10`

Note that this only works because your range happens to coincide with 'all two digit numbers except 10'.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, as long as your requirement is actually `10 <= x < 100`, as it would include `10`:

```
grep ^..$ query.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, `grep` is not the best tool to use in this context.  But, if you absolutely must...

```
grep -E '^((1[1-9])|([2-9][0-9]))$'
```